# How could stress possibly increase in a food-gathering population

Tags: evolution

I want to create a modern population which is adapted to stress. Meaning people could take immense mental pressures without getting into mental disorders. I thought a way to do this would be to bring stress increasing factors in the life of the ancestors of this population nearly a 1000 generations before. (These ancestors live in a forest setting) 
What I would like to know is
1. Whether such a thing would really make my population stress-proof ?
2. If so how do I introduce stress in the life of the ancestors (there is no fear of losing your job/failing in an exam) ?
3. How much impact could fear of ghosts have ?
Have tagged it as evolution. Couldn't think of any better/any other tag.

Comment: If people are adapted to the stress: Would it still be "stress"? Or do you just mean what we now think "stress" is? If you are used to something you rarely think it's stressful. Maybe it's enough to just change the normal stress-level and culture of dealing with stress in your current society.

Comment: @Secespitus Though I don't get what both of them mean according to you I think you mean physical and mental. I here am talking about mental

Comment: Stress is a natural mechanism against threats. It's actually an evolutionary advantage. Stress becomes problematic when it's high for long periods of time, but that kinda happens only in our artificial environments.

Comment: @Faerindel  But I want to avoid the mental disorder part when it gets high

Comment: I believe what you want is closely related to the reasons of the stress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're describing would best be termed 'adaptability'. Just having a harsh condition or three for a few millennia would only produce people adapted to those particular conditions. However, if you have a situation that produces ongoing, dangerous changes, then the species would become suited to dealing with emergent situations. Options for this include:

1) variable star, producing radiation, changing weather patterns, etc

2) blowing up a moon. Orbital strikes from debris change the landscape, weather, sea levels. This happens over a period of time as chunk orbits decay

3) high tectonic activity. Mountains rise and fall over days due to gravitational stresses induced by a co-orbiting planet with an irregular orbit

4) adaptive predators, newly arrived to the ecosystem

5) fickle deities

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Whether such a thing would really make my population stress-proof?

Not exactly. It makes them deal with this specific stress. If e.g. gathering before the winter (Remember: Winter is coming!) causes extreme stress to the people, they would have invented a way to deal with it, e.g. invent something to store the fruits, berries and herbs. But yet, the uprising of another violent tribe will definitely cause stress.

> 2. If so how do I introduce stress in the life of the ancestors

Make something happen that breaks their routine. A sudden drought or a flood. Another tribe. A sudden allergic reaction to some berry.

> 3. How much impact could fear of ghosts have?

It depends. Normally (as long as we can talk about normally, when it comes to ghosts) ghosts are bound to a specific area. If your ghosts work that way. The gatherers get scared a few times and go to a less haunted place in the forest. Or they will learn to deal with the ghost, like, hey if we sacrifice some cucumber, the ghosts won't be around for a few days.